# Почему при выставлении value, input сдвигается вниз?

Tags: css

http://xxsusanooxx.github.io/Sapper/

Я хочу написать сапера, и пока что я уже сделал функцию, которая при нажатии пробегает по соседним клеткам и считает количество мин рядом. Она ставит это значение, но при этом почему-то кнопка сдвигается вниз. Если кто знает, дайте знать, пожалуйста, почему так происходит.

Вот мой код:

```js
var field = document.getElementById("field");

var nOfCells = 100,
  nOfMines = 13,
  widthOfCell = 30;

field.style.width = Math.sqrt(nOfCells) * widthOfCell;
field.style.height = Math.sqrt(nOfCells) * widthOfCell;

for (var i = 0; i < nOfCells; i++) {
  var cell = document.createElement('input');
  cell.type = 'submit';
  cell.id = i;
  cell.className = 'cell';
  cell.value = '';
  field.appendChild(cell);
  var r = getRandomInt(1, 6);
  if (r === 1) {
    cell.classList.add('hide-mine');
    cell.onclick = clickOnMine;
  } else {
    cell.onclick = clickOnSafeCell;
  }

}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {

  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function clickOnMine() {
  var mines = document.getElementsByClassName('hide-mine');
  for (var i = 0; i < mines.length; i++) {
    mines[i].classList.add('activeted-mine');
    mines[i].disable = 'disabled';
  }
  alert('Game Over');
}

function clickOnSafeCell() {
  var nOfMines = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var element = document.getElementById(parseInt(this.id) - 11 + i);
    if (element.classList.contains('hide-mine')) {
      nOfMines++;
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    element = document.getElementById(parseInt(this.id) + 9 + i);
    if (element.classList.contains('hide-mine')) {
      nOfMines++;
    }
  }
  element = document.getElementById(parseInt(this.id) - 1);
  if (element.classList.contains('hide-mine')) {
    nOfMines++;
  }
  element = document.getElementById(parseInt(this.id) + 1);
  if (element.classList.contains('hide-mine')) {
    nOfMines++;
  }
  this.value = nOfMines;

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: black;
}
.field {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 120px;
  margin-bottom: 120px;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.conteiner {
  text-align: center;
}
input {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.activeted-mine {
  background-color: red;
}
.hide-mine {} .marked-mine {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.safe-cell {
  color: green;
}
.blank-cell {}
```

```html
<div class="conteiner">
  <div class="field" id="field"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте к стилю input строку выравнивания:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Comment: Обалдеть, заработало! А почему так? На сколько я знаю, vetical align служит для выравнивания содержимого, а не самого элемента.

Comment: vertical-align применяется к строчным элементам (или их имитациям) и выравнивает себя относительно соседей. Выравнивание содержимого происходит только если элемент - ячейка таблицы (или её имитация).

Answer (score 0):

style.css
18 строка - 
padding: 7px; поставь

Comment: и что? Какой в этом смысл?

Comment: сдвига не будет, тут проблема в css а не в самом скрипте

Comment: я попробовал - не получилось. Такой же сдвиг.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?